# Defining a function, $\Pi(x_1, x_2, ... x_n)$ that will multiply all inputs together.

Tags: functions, products

I want to define a function that outputs the product of all numbers I input. My reasoning is I have defined say 10 variables: $a$ through $k$. If I want to multiply them all together, writing:

$a \times b \times c \times d \times etc...$
is not what I would like.

Also, I don't think I could use $\prod_i^n$ notation without defining a function because each variable is a unique letter, rather than say $x_1, x_2, x_3$, etc.

Right now, I have:

$\Pi(x_1, x_2 \ldots x_n) := \prod_{i=1}^ni$

with the intent of seeing

$\Pi(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k)$ rather than $a \times b \times c \times d \times e \times f \times g \times h \times j \times k$ between each variable.

Can I get some help or tips on correctly formatting?

Comment: Is this a question about some kind of computer programming?

Comment: I recommend to create a vector, say, $x=[a;b;c;...]$ then $\prod(x)$.

Comment: @kimchilover it is not. I'm working with dimensions of things. So if I have 3 boxes with each box having a uniform $w, h, l$, then to get my total volume I would have to multiply all 4 together.

Comment: @CyeWaldman thanks makes sense to me

Comment: How about a notation like $A\mapsto\prod_{a\in A} a$ for finite sets of numbers $A$?

Comment: @kimchilover I like that answer a lot. Thanks

Comment: Or better, for finite _multisets_ of numbers.